# Execute a SQL query from C# console application and get its result written in a file

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have written the below code to execute a set of SQL Server scripts placed in a directory.

The code is working fine but I want to get the script execution result written into a file (like writing the results in a log file). Please help.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["UtilsDBConnection"].ConnectionString;
    string path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["folderPath"];

    DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(path);

    FileInfo[] sqlfiles = d.GetFiles("*.sql");

    SqlCommand cm;

    using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))

    try
    {
        cnn.Open();

        // Console.WriteLine("Connection Open ! ");
        foreach (FileInfo file in sqlfiles)
        {
            string script = file.OpenText().ReadToEnd();

            using (cm = cnn.CreateCommand())
                cm.CommandText = script;

            cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        cnn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       // Console.WriteLine("Can not open connection ! ", ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are creating a command, setting `CommandText` to it, `Dispose`ing it, and *after* that executing it.

Comment: What results do you expect in a non-query ? There are no results other than an Error-Code. You Code has nothing to do with your question. You do not even try to open a file for writing nor you execute a query.

Comment: I would use SQLCMD.EXE which is a msdn command line utility which is also built into a Power Shell.  The is an output option to create CSV.  SQLCMD.exe takes same Command Text Query that you are using c#.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/command-prompt-utility-reference-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ExecuteNonQuery` is used for update,insert and delete, and returns a integer.
You can simply save it to a file using `File.WriteAllText()` method.

If your query are select, consider instead using `ExecuteReader()` method.
So iterate over the response and write a line for each row returned.